# How can I change the default Django Form name?

Tags: python, django, forms, bootstrap-4

In order to have a better overview on which page I'm loading which form, I would like to change the name with which it is accessed in the template. By default as far as I know it is set to 'form'. In the snipped below I'm trying to load the form with 'form_inv' but that doesn't work.

```
 {% extends "dashboard/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Create Investment</legend>
                {{ form_inv|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

The following is the Model I created and the respective view.

The Model:

```
class MoneyGroups(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    size = models.IntegerField()
    interest = models.FloatField()
```

The Django View:

```
class MoneyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = MoneyGroups
    template_name = 'dashboard/scenario_form.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'investments'
    fields = ['title', 'size', 'interest']
    success_url = '/dashboard/'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user #add the author to the form before it is submitted
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

What parameter do I have to change/add in my model or view in order to change the name with which I can access it in the template?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you would want to do this but add get_context_data method to your view like so:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context[‘form_inv’] = context[‘form’]
    return context
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. This worked! My hope was, that I could load 2 different forms on a page, when I name them differently. But this seems to be not the case.

Comment: @SirIsacson you certainly can use 2 forms in the same view but for the second one you will need to add it as a different name and update a few more methods, I can give an example if you let me know exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! I finally managed to do it. I'm pretty new to django so everything is still quite a struggle.

Comment: Your welcome, glad I could be of help, don’t forget to mark it as right please